# Is there any possible way is can fix this impossible error? (answer: probably yes)

Tags: lua

I am trying to create a tycoon style game where you can touch buttons to unlock new items.

I am very new to scripting so this is probably the reason why it doesn't work. Pretty much, the problem is that if you don't have enough cash to buy the item, the notification doesn't come up and the print function doesn't do anything. And if you do have enough money, nothing happens at all. Again, new to scripting, so this is probably a very easy fix and completely
my fault. Any help would be extremely helpful.

This is my script:

```lua
local TycoonModel = script.Parent.Parent.Parent
local Mainitems = TycoonModel:FindFirstChild("Mainitems")
local ButtonTwo = script.Parent
local Buttons = script.Parent.Parent
local player = game:GetService("Players")
local Price = script.Parent.Price
local CashButton2 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Mainitems.CashButton2
local CashButton2Script = Mainitems.CashButton2.CashButton2Script
local ScreenPart2 = TycoonModel:FindFirstChild("Mainitems").CashButton2.ScreenPart2
local ButtonPart2 = TycoonModel:FindFirstChild("Mainitems").CashButton2.ButtonPart2
local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
local Cash = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
local Values = TycoonModel:FindFirstChild("Values")
local Price = script.Parent.Price
local NotEnough = game.StarterGui.NotEnoughCash.NotEnoughNote

TycoonModel.Mainitems.CashButton2.ButtonPart2.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
    if Cash.Value <= Price then
Cash.Value -= Price 
ButtonPart2.Transparency = 0
ButtonPart2.CanCollide = true 
ScreenPart2.Transparency = 0
ScreenPart2.CanCollide = true 
CashButton2Script.Disabled = false
    else
print("Player doesn't have enough cash")
NotEnough.Visible = true 
wait(3)
NotEnough.Visible = false 
    end
end)
```

Error is " Workspace.TycoonModel.Buttons.ButtonTwo.ButtonScript:18: attempt to compare number <= Instance"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like price is an instance in your workspace (maybe an int value?) so you will need to access its value using something like `if Cash.Value <= Price.Value` instead of just `if Cash.Value <= Price`